# lifecycle function are not getting called on back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use code from [This Link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) creating multiple fragment wizard page. On the first fragment there is `EditText and Next Button`. On clicking Next Button, I'm disabling these controls and then navigating to 2nd fragment(page).

Now when I press back button using the below code

```
mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
```

Fragment get changed back to first activity. But the EditText and Next Button are still disable.

I want to enable these button on back button clicking. But not getting any call in the overridden  `onResume()`, `onStart()`, `onViewStateRestored()` function of FirstFragment class.

Answer (score 0):

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == 0) { // first fragment
                    // enable the views
                } 
                if (position == 1) { // Second fragment
                    // disable the views
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Use the **onPageSelected** to disable and enable the buttons depending on the position you are at

Comment: How to get FirstFragment class instance inside onPageSelected() function?

Comment: Or can you please tell how to get the view instance on basic of position

Comment: Why do you want the instance of the fragment? @dearvivekkumar

Comment: so as to enable the fragment. By replacing the comment in code snippet which you have mention " // enable the views"

Comment: Or is there any other option to enable the view?

Comment: Post your code of the 2 fragments xml and the main activity xml in order to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101393/discussion-between-dearvivekkumar-and-malek-hijazi).

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is not actually paused or disabled when you go thru pager (depends on your nr. of active pages setting), it is still there. You should send event from your Adapter to Fragment when changing pages.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to send signal to Fragment.

Comment: Integrate interface http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html from your activity to fragment. Then just send it a signal from pager when it becomes the active fragment